# .htaccess with partially matching domain name

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have a really basic set of rewrite conditions in my .htaccess file, which doesn't work for one condition.

I have run it through a .htaccess tester which claims it should work, but it doesn't on the real site.

I have site.com, site.com.au, anothersite.com.au which should all redirect to site.com.au

```
RewriteBase /

# Domain Aliases  
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I visit anothersite.com.au, it 301s successfully to site.com.au, however when I visit site.com it just stays at site.com and doesn't 301. I have used `^` and `$` which should limit the match to the exact .com.au domain but it still seems to just decide that .com is enough and doesn't redirect.

I have also tried using individual rules for all of the domains- this behaves in the same way.

Is anyone able to shed some light on this for me?